# Can nodes represent population groups (with population size as an attribute) in R?

Tags: r, igraph

So I'm working to build a network model representing mobility through a US county. I have been able to build a weighted network model where travel times between zipcodes are the weighted edges, but I'm not sure how to correctly introduce the idea of the node as a population into my model. The code and example of my data is below:

```
edgelist  weight
zip1 zip2  5
zip2 zip1  10
zip1 zip3  4
zip3 zip1  6
zip2 zip3  8
zip3 zip2  1
```

(this is an edgelist, a simpler way of representing a distance/adjacency matrix)
the matrix format would look like this:

```
    zip1  zip2   zip3
zip1 0      5      4
zip2 10     0      8
zip3 6      1      0

dat <- read.csv("file.csv", ....)
m = as.matrix(dat)
net = network(m, matrix.type="adjacency", directed=FALSE, ignore.eval=FALSE,   
names.eval="value")
plot(net, edge.lwd=net%e%'value'*.1)
```

The end goal is to run a network simulation where population flows in and out of nodes at a rate set by the strength/weight of the edge, however I want to be able to have the node remain infected even if there is one person in the population infected, and to keep track of how many infected/uninfected.

i.e. population A (500 people) to population B (700 people) has a strength A->B of 5 and B->A of 10, so in one time step, the model will look like this
Time step 1: A (500), B (700), ....
Time step 2: A (505), B (495), ....

Population flow in/out would assume only the uninfected population amt would be able to migrate between nodes.

If anyone if familiar with STELLA, this is quite simple to model with a few nodes, but is hard to model large numbers of nodes because to have in and outflows that are connected to everything else, the edges are exponentially large, and it gets cluttered and difficult to build. That's why I'm trying to learn R, but am having difficulties understanding and reading the documentation. The packages I've looked at so far are Epimodel (utilizes statnet, ergm, etc.) and igraph.

Any suggestions on how to do this? Looking at documentation, I think I need to be playing with vertex.attr, but I'm not sure, so commentary would be helpful - thanks in advance!

Comment: This does seem to violate the prohibition on requests for recommendations for packages and for questions where the coding strategy is unclear. I'm not saying I wouldn't be interested in seeing a good answer but this Q is probably a better fit for CrossValidated.com

Comment: fair enough - should I delete the question? I think I figured out a solution anyways.

Comment: Agree with deletion.